# Frama-C option -no-simplify-cfg does not work

Tags: frama-c

I am using Frama-C to compute a slice of a C program. I want the sliced program to look like the original without code transformation. However in the resulting slice I always have goto statements and labels.
I use the command:

```
frama-c -no-simplify-cfg -main test -slice-assert test test.c -then-on 'Slicing export' -print -ocode result.c
```

I compiled Frama-C from the latest Oxygen release on a Windows machine under Cygwin.

Comment: Your question would be better if you showed a small example of C program and the result. As written, it can only be understood by people who already know Frama-C very well. If you provided an example, everyone could understand what your question is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ frama-c -kernel-help
[...]
-simplify-cfg   remove break, continue and switch statement[sic] before
                analyzes[sic] (opposite option is -no-simplify-cfg)
```

Option -no-simplify-cfg does not do anything because not simplifying
`break`, `continue` and `switch` statements is already the default.

The front-end does introduce `goto` statements and labels as targets
for these in a non-optional fashion as the translation of other constructs, for
instance `||` and `&&`.
There is no way to disable this treatment.
The slicing plug-in selects parts of the AST and erases others,
therefore the `goto` statements appear in its output.

Frama-C's slicing plug-in is the only slicer I know that produces
compilable slices for C programs. If you need a better slicer that
does not introduce `goto` statements, you may need to write your own.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was looking for slicers in the internet for some time and indeed the frama-c slicer seems to be the most advanced one.
BR
Harald